# A better approach to add big numbers, Project Euler #13

Tags: c

[Project euler problem 13](https://projecteuler.net/problem=13)

For C program I tried the problem with practical approach, i.e. not defining the data in the code but rather using scanf for taking input.

But I cannot understand why the output is wrong! I get 1373762303 while it should be 5537376230.
It seems ok for 2-3 numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define NUM 50
#define STRINGS 100
#define OUTPUT 10
int main(void) {
    char str[STRINGS][NUM+1];
    int answer[NUM+1] = {0};
    int carry = 0, out_digits = OUTPUT;

    for(int i = 0; i < STRINGS; i++){
        scanf("%s", str[i]);
        for(int j = NUM; j >=0; j--){
            answer[j] += (str[i][j] - 48) + carry;
            if(answer[j] > 9){
                carry = answer[j] / 10;
                answer[j] %= 10;
            }else{
                carry = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\r\n");
    printf("%d",carry);
    for(int j = 0; j < OUTPUT-1; j++){
        printf("%d",answer[j]);
    }
    printf("\r\n--------------------------------------------------");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it can be considered correct to discuss here Project Euler problems

Comment: What is yout input? What is your output? And what is your _expected_ output?

Comment: @Jabberwocky showing the *expected* output would definitely be a **spoiler**.

Comment: Note that `for(int j = NUM; j >=0; j--)` is indexing beyond the string's digits.

Comment: @WeatherVane He could give the input, expected and actual output for a test case, not the real problem.

Comment: You have not considered that the resulting carry might be more than 1 digit.

Comment: @WeatherVane you are write, i did edited that. but still answer is wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane Intermediate carry was the issue. You solved it! Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote that the intermediate carry might be larger than 1.

Comment: You can read the first 13 digits of each number into `long long`s, add them and print the first 10 digits. All other digits will not make a significant carry to change the first 10 digits. An example (with fewer numbers to not spoiler the result): https://ideone.com/Cgt3dJ

Comment: @mch i like that idea, but if i provide a 50 number input to `scanf("%10llu",&num);` it won't give proper answer.

Comment: You can read the whole line into a buffer and then you set the 0-terminator correct and use `sscanf` to get the number. `buffer[13] = 0; sscanf(buffer, "%llu", &num);`. You could also copy/paste the file into the source file, make a initializer list out of it and remove the last 37 digit of each number, like I did in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf`fills in the array you give it with a string constructed from the input including a null terminator byte. You allocate 51 bytes correctly but when you start adding the digits, you start at index 50 which is the index of the nul byte. The actual digits are from indexes 0 to 49.

This means that you will get a carry into the units digit of your answer at some point because the answer for that digit is calculated as

```
answer[50] += (str[i][50] - 48) + carry;
//                        ^^^^ correction applied for ASCII
```

Another issue is that you forget to reset carry to zero at the beginning of adding each new number.

This might work (not tested) but it still doesn't really handle overflows in the top digits

```
for(int i = 0; i < STRINGS; i++){
    scanf("%s", str[i]);
    carry = 0;            // Reset the carry
    for(int j = NUM - 1; j >=0; j--){
        answer[j] += (str[i][j] - 48) + carry;
        if(answer[j] > 9){
            carry = answer[j] / 10;
            answer[j] %= 10;
        }else{
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's true, but their sum is 0 and so is any carry.

Comment: @WeatherVane No. Their sum is `0 - 48`

Comment: But it still does not generate a carry.

Comment: Your comment about not clearing the carry is good, but the compensating indexing error does clear the carry.

Comment: @WeatherVane No it doesn't. In no Universe does `-48 % 10 == 0`

Comment: `(answer[50] > 9` is false, so `else{  carry = 0; }` is executed.

Comment: @WeatherVane OK That is true. but it looks like I did obliquely reference the correct answer which was losing the overflow from the top digit. I'll leave my answer here because the indexing is still wrong.

Comment: @JeremyP you are right. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it was the missing carry over when adding the two numbers. Following is the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define NUM 50
#define STRINGS 100
#define OUTPUT 10
int main(void) {
    char str[STRINGS][NUM+1];
    int answer[NUM+1] = {0};
    int carry = 0, out_digits = OUTPUT, intm_carry = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < STRINGS; i++){
        scanf("%s", str[i]);
        for(int j = NUM; j >=0; j--){
            answer[j] += (str[i][j] - 48) + carry;
            if(answer[j] > 9){
                carry = answer[j] / 10;
                answer[j] %= 10;
            }else{
                carry = 0;
            }
        }
        intm_carry += carry;
        carry = 0;
    }
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\r\n");
    printf("%d", intm_carry);
    for(int j = 0; j < OUTPUT-1; j++){
        printf("%d",answer[j]);
    }
    printf("\r\n--------------------------------------------------");
    return 0;
}
```